# Android - Broadcast Reciever to detect when phone just connected to tower?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to detect when the GSM phone has just been connected to the Network(from cell tower not available to cell tower connected). For this i set broadcast reciever 
**AIRPLANE_MODE** (turns off) and **BOOT_COMPLETE**, when these two get fired i will loop for a while until Network is detected. But aside from this the phone might be in a location where

> Cell Tower is simply not available

how can i detect such a situation?

Comment: "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" gets fired under all situations when connectivity state changes.So i just used that single action. The thing is it is not available in the dropdown list of Actions in the manifest. No permissions need to be set for this. It seems to work fine this far.

Comment: As mentioned above , i need to detect if device has service provider connectivity, not data connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver set up with an intent filter for "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityActionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In that receiver, you can look at the intent's extras to figure out if you have a connection or not.  I do it as follows:

```
@Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
{
    Intent startIntent;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String action;
    int updateType;

    action = intent.getAction();
    if ( !action.equals( ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ) )
        return;

    /* If we don't have a connection, nothing to do */
    if ( intent.getBooleanExtra( ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false ) )
        return;
```

If that second if check is true that means there's no network connection, so the receiver exits.  Next time there's a connectivity change, the receiver is activated again and runs this check again.  Once it passes the check, then I proceed to do whatever I do.

Comment: i cant find the CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE option in the list of receiver actions. i am working with GB 2.3.3. I also checked in API level 16.

Comment: "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" does not showup in the regular drop-down list of receiver actions in the manifest file.But it seems to work when i use it. Is there some place where i can get a list of all actions and if possible their description. The DOCS dont seem to have a list of sorts, and i am not a big fan of their explanations.

Comment: On the emulator the broadcast receiver is fired when the phone is switched off, airplane mode turned on/off. But on the my Device a Samsung Galaxy S running GB, it fires only when i enable / disable 3G, that is the data network changes.

Comment: This receiver only fires when the data network connection changes.  I'm not sure if there's one that does any cell network change.  I'll do a bit of digging when I get some time, might be a few days though.

Comment: You could investigate using [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to listen for any changes in the cell network.

Answer (score 0):

The CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE seems to work on emulator for airplane mode , but on my device it only fired for 3G Network state change. Now i had to settle for SERVICE_STATE_CHANGE, it get fired for switching between Airplane mode and sudden loss of tower. For restart i used BOOT_COMPLETED.